# Why there is "index exceeded the number of group boundaries" in this code?

Tags: c#, arrays

For this code in Visual Studio

```
Point[,] point = new Point[9, 10];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
 {
  for(int j = 0; i < 10; j++)
   {
    point[i, j].X = i;//mark1
    point[i, j].Y = j;    
   }
 }
```

at //mark1,system tell me"index exceeded the number of group boundaries"

Why?

[image]

Comment: You have a typo in your inner loop condition: " for(int j = 0; i < 10; j++)"

Comment: That `i` should be a `j`.

Comment: To diagnose this, you could have run it in the debugger and observed the value of `j` when the error hit. You could then have seen that the value was 10, therefore outside the array bounds - then worked out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing

```
for (int j = 0; i < 10; j++)
```

so the condition `i < 10` which is maybe a typo is causing your loop to go out of the range in the array (you are then trying to access the eleement **0, 10** in the array)

replace that with:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
```